# How can I fake hard links in fake filesystem in Python tests?

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I'd like to check if Python production code interacting with the filesystem considers hard links (file names pointing to the same inode) the right way.

In a unit test I'm using a fake filesystem (created with [`pytest` fixture `tmp_path`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html#the-tmp-path-fixture), is a `pathlib/pathlib2.Path` object) and would like to fake hard links in it.

The fake filesystem in the test shall contain three hard links `hard_link_0...2.txt` pointing at the same inode in the fake filesystem.

```
hard_link_0.txt
hard_link_1.txt
/dir
  hard_link_2.txt
```

Comment: If you tell us what the test looks like, maybe. The question is a bit too general otherwise.

Comment: I've updated the question with just enough info.

Comment: I still don't get what you're trying to do. What is a fake filesystem? Does `root` directory actually exist somewhere, or do you just talk about pathlib objects? Do you need to create a hard link, test whether something is a hard link, fake creating a hard link but create a soft link instead, fake creating a hard link but make a file copy instead, fake creating a hard link but obtain a pathlib-like object that behaves as if it refers to a hard link...? (besides, pathlib does not have a way to create a hard link in the first place...)

Comment: I am talking about pathlib objects. I need to create hard links during test setup to check if the production code handles them correctly. I've updated the question. The workaround for pathlibs inability to create hard links is exactly what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `tmp_path` creates an *actual* directory (as opposed to mocking pathlib), you can treat everything in `tmp_path` normally. Thus, to create a hard link, you can use `os.link(srcpath, dstpath)`, as you normally would (from Python 3.6+; otherwise, use `os.link(str(srcpath), str(dstpath))`).